# Cycles transparent node brighter texture color in blender 2.79

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, transparency

Blender 2.79 alpha transparent part brighter color.
[image]
Blender 2.78 work fine no problem.
[image]
Material simple alpha is black and white vertex color.
[image]
Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem but maybe it is that you have to check the color of your Transparent BSDF node? It looks like by default it is not 100% white, so maybe you have to push it to 100%

Comment: I have enviroment HDR light texture and one sun light.  If deletet sun light brighten area fixed. Sun lamp strength realy big 100.